# Errors for \subfloat environment

Tags: errors, subfloats

I am getting these errors (below) for each `\subfloat` when using this code. It has worked fine in the rest of my thesis, but suddenly there is a problem. Note that I exported all previous work from LyX, and these are the first new figures and subfigures I am adding ("inserted text" code <> switched so they would show).

```
! Missing $ inserted.>inserted text> $ }

! Extra }, or forgotten $.<argument> ...s/Chapter4/Style_Groups-SG1-MAE2445}}

! Extra }, or forgotten $.\sf@@@subfloat ...de \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {#4}\@tempdima =\wd \@tempboxa...}

! Missing $ inserted.>inserted text>$ }

! Missing } inserted.>inserted text>} }

! Missing } inserted.>inserted text>} }
```

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[MAE 2445]{includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/Chapter4/Style_Groups-SG1-MAE2445}
}

\subfloat[MAE 2459]{includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/Chapter4/Style_Groups-SG1-MAE2459}
}

\protect\caption{Style Group 1}\label{SG1-all}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Apparently my coding skills are not up to snuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `\includegraphics`. You have missed `\` in the beginning. Further, don't leave blank lines as commented in code.

```
\documentclass[english,demo]{report}  %% remove demo in your file
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}   %% you need graphicx
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[MAE 2445]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/Chapter4/Style_Groups-SG1-MAE2445}
}
%  No blank line
\subfloat[MAE 2459]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/Chapter4/Style_Groups-SG1-MAE2459}
}    
\protect\caption{Style Group 1}\label{SG1-all}   %% why protect? Use optional argument if needed like \caption[optional arg]{caption here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :facepalm Sorry to have wasted your time on this- Thx!